# Proving joint convexity in stochastic linear problems with fixed recourse

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, stochastic-analysis

In Birge's stochastic optimization book, we have the following formulation where $\zeta$ is a random variable:

$z(x,\zeta) = c^Tx + \min \{q^Ty|Wy = h -Tx, y\geq 0 \} \\ s.t. \ AX = b, x \geq0$

In this model $W,h,T,q$ are all dependent on the scenario $\zeta$. However, when we look for the fixed recourse case, $W$ and $q$ are fixed parameters.

Now the question is in Birge's book, it is said that in the fixed recourse case $z(x,\zeta)$ is jointly convex in  $x$ and $\zeta$. The explanation is the following:

The problem can be written as

$z(x,h,T) = c^Tx + Q(x,h,T) + \delta(x | Ax = b, x\geq0 )$

where $\delta(x|X)$ is the of the point $x$ for set $X$. This $z(x,h,T)$ is concluded to be jointly convex in $(x,h,T)$ or $(x,\zeta)$.

I don't see how one can conclude immediately.

- What is the indicator function? How is it defined?
- What is $Q$?
- How can we conclude it is convex?
- Is it different to say "it is convex in both $x,\zeta$" than "it is jointly convex in these two variables"?

Comment: Did you appreciate my answer? Any thoughts on the convexity of $Q$?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt tick it yet since I am stuck to complete it. But, that was helpful ! Thank you :)

Comment: Have you made any progress yet?

Answer (score 1):

1. The indicator function takes the value $0$ if $Ax=b, x \geq 0$, and the value $\infty$ otherwise.
2. Just by comparing functions, it must be that $Q(x,h,T) = \min \{q^Ty|Wy = h -Tx, y\geq 0 \}$.
3. $z$ is convex since it is the sum of convex functions. The first function is linear, the last function is clearly convex, but I struggle with $Q$ which is not jointly convex in $(x,T)$.
4. *Convex in both $x,\zeta$* is ambiguous. For example, is $f(x,\zeta) = x\zeta$ convex in both $x$ and $\zeta$?